# Fetching a large Blob to a byte[] throws NoClassDefFoundError with openJPA, DB2

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2, websphere, blob, openjpa

I have an Entity with the following field.

```java
@Lob
@Column(name = "image", nullable = false)
private byte[] image;
```

Persisting my entity with a 5MB image worked without problems however when I try to fetch it a get an Exception. (smaller image sizes work flawlessly though!).
It is a NoClassDefFoundError *but it happens only with this large image*.

I posted the full stacktrace here. I hope you can point me to a direction. Maybe there is some jdbc property like maxBlobSize that I don't know of :( 
TY

```
2011-06-21 13:48:11 [DEBUG] EXCEPTION LOGGER GOT NoClassDefFoundError Message: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.d Cause: ClassNotFoundException CauseMsg: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.d
java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.d.c(d.java:1454)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.a(ic.java:944)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ic.T(ic.java:1948)
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ym.getBlob(ym.java:1356)
com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getBlob(WSJdbcResultSet.java:740)
org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingResultSet.getBlob(DelegatingResultSet.java:580)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.getBlob(DBDictionary.java:541)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.getBytes(DBDictionary.java:604)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.ResultSetResult.getBytesInternal(ResultSetResult.java:290)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.ResultSetResult.getObjectInternal(ResultSetResult.java:421)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.getObject(AbstractResult.java:694)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerStrategies.loadDataStore(HandlerStrategies.java:217)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.HandlerFieldStrategy.load(HandlerFieldStrategy.java:186)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.load(FieldMapping.java:813)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1060)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:1012)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:378)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:278)
com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.initialize(WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.java:144)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:111)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:913)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:871)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:793)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:986)
com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.load(WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.java:107)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:278)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl$SelectResult.load(SelectImpl.java:2415)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.AbstractResult.load(AbstractResult.java:272)
org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.InstanceResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(InstanceResultObjectProvider.java:56)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.singleResult(QueryImpl.java:1294)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1221)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:990)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:848)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:779)
org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:525)
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:254)
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:317)
com.ibm.ompetestweb.ejb.beans.ImageServerBean.findImageByRftLogfileSource(ImageServerBean.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5874)
com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:586)
com.ibm.ompetestweb.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.onMethodCall(LoggingInterceptor.java:53)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:566)
com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:217)
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5766)
com.ibm.ompetestweb.ejb.interfaces.EJSLocal0SLImageServerBean_abf730e0.findImageByRftLogfileSource(EJSLocal0SLImageServerBean_abf730e0.java)
com.ibm.ompetestweb.ui.servlets.ImageServlet.doGet(ImageServlet.java:43)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
com.ibm.ws390.channel.xmem.XMemConnLink.ready(XMemConnLink.java:844)
com.ibm.ws390.channel.xmem.XMemInboundChannel.handleRequest(XMemInboundChannel.java:340)
com.ibm.ws390.xmem.XMemSRBridgeImpl.httpinvoke(XMemSRBridgeImpl.java:104)
com.ibm.ws390.xmem.XMemSRCppUtilities.httpinvoke(XMemSRCppUtilities.java:74)
com.ibm.ws390.orb.ServerRegionBridge.httpinvoke(ServerRegionBridge.java:215)
com.ibm.ws390.orb.ORBEJSBridge.httpinvoke(ORBEJSBridge.java:281)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
com.ibm.ws390.orb.parameters.HTTPInvoke.HTTPInvokeParmSetter(HTTPInvoke.java:101)
com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.nativeRunApplicationThread(Native Method)
com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:464)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$ZOSWorker.run(ThreadPool.java:1763)
```

Comment: What is the size of the 'image' LOB column in the DB?

Comment: It's a BLOB(5M). I'm pretty sure the image is smaller than the blobsize. (It should have thrown an SQLException on insert if not) But I will try by raising to BLOB(10M) tomorrow.

Comment: "Persisting my entity with a 5MB image worked without problems however when I try to fetch it a get an Exception." If it is a 5MB column it could be truncated when it is being saved and then it may not be serializable when it is fetched, hence the noClassDefFound.

Comment: Reuploaded to a 10Meg column, still the same. The error is strange anyway because `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.d` is in the db2jcc.jar that is used by the websphere all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the driver property fullyMaterializeLobData. Most likely the driver is attempting to throw you and exception but the class for it is missing from drivers. Also, I would recommend migrating to the type-4 drivers if ever possible.